# ImageView not getting back to uitable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have used the following code to display image when I click on the custom table cell.
But it shows the black screen and also its not returning to the table view when I click on the black screen.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = tableView.visibleCells[indexPath.row];
    UIViewController *imageVC = [UIViewController new];
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    imageVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageVC.view.frame];
    cell.vendorImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullImg]]];
    //    cell.imageView.image = fullImg;
    imageView.image = cell.vendorImage.image;
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:imageView.hidden=YES];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];
    [self presentViewController:imageVC animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't add imageView as a subView to you view controller

Comment: Your action must be a selector, you cannot use it that way and it is not a good way to show thumbnail.

Comment: What is the relation between imageView and your imageVC? Do you want to add imageView in to your imageVC?

Comment: 1. Your imageView is not added to your imageVC. 2. You didn't handle the tap gesture

Comment: I don't think you know much about iOS development in general. I suggest you clear up your basics first.

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding the image to the `imageVC`. You are presenting an empty view controller, which is black.

You should create a subclass of `UIViewController`. Add a `NSImage` property to the view controller. Add an image view to the class and init it in `loadView` (or in an Interface Builder file (xib or storyboard)).

```
- (void)loadView {
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:...];

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:...];

    [contentView addSubview:self.imageView];

    self.view = contentView;
}
```

Set the image to the image view in `viewWillAppear:`.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.imageView.image = self.image;
}
```

Add a dismiss method.

```
- (void)dismiss {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Then present the view controller like this:

```
MyImageViewController *imageVC = [[MyImageViewController alloc] init];
cell.vendorImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:fullImg]]];
imageVC.image = cell.vendorImage.image;
imageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismiss)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGR];
[self presentViewController:imageVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: It displays the image but suddenly it turns to blank screen

Answer (score 0):

No need for creating a new UIViewController instead you can use UIView and can add this view to the current view above the table view and add the image view over it.